# The menu does not appear in the map activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-menu

I am trying to create a menu with this option `None, Normal, Terrain, Satellite, Hybrid` (Google map) in the map activity to enable the users to select their desired map type but the menu in not being shown in the Map activity.

I have tried to add `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` to the `onCreateOptionsMenu` before `inflater` but without success.

How can I fix it?

**Map activity:**

public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.map_menu, menu);
    System.out.println("ABC MAP onCreateOptionsMenu was invoked.");

    return true;
}

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.mapTypeNone:
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);                
            break;

        case R.id.mapTypeNormal:
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);              
            break;

        case R.id.mapTypeSatellite:
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);               
            break;

        case R.id.mapTypeTerrain:
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);             
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeHybrid:
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);              
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

}

**map_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeNormal"
        android:title="Normal"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeSatellite"
        android:title="Satellitte"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeTerrain"
        android:title="Terrain"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeHybrid"
        android:title="Hybrid"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeNone"
        android:title="None"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check what your MapActivity.java is extending.

If it is `extends FragmentActivity` then change it to `extends AppCompatActivity`.

and in your styles make sure this ..

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        ...
</style>
```

Add it in the Build.gradle (Module:app)
inside the dependencies

```
dependencies {
    ..
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

}
```

Comment: Yes it extends FragmentActivity and I tried to replace it but I am getting `AppCompatActivity cannot be resolved to a type`.

Comment: Where can I find the <style>? I dont have it

Comment: go to values folder inside the res folder

Comment: I had to change it from `FragmentActivity` to `ActionBarActivity` and it works it. Please add it to your answer then I will accept it.

Comment: @TheLight `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated, use `AppCompatActivity`, and accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

Extend "AppCompatActivity" and add "setSupportActionBar(toolbar)" inside the activity onCreate.